# How to deal with damaged sdd (fdisk does not detect it)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an SSD with bad blocks. It stops windows from loading, however second OS - Linux is working great. Originally it was working even with bad blocks. I have made a low-level copy of the disk and currently working from new disk, but I try to restore the old disk also. So I run AOEMI Parion Assistant and make surface scan, hoping it will replace bad blocks and at least I will be able to load windows. But no luck - surface scan find more bad blocks than it was before. Now I can not access my old disk at old. AOEMI partion assistant could not access it anymore. Fdisk does not see it as device. dmesg have such output:

```
   [  403.641098] scsi host2: uas
[  403.642898] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     KINGSTON  SUV400S37480G   8102 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  403.646831] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  403.649404] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 937703088 512-byte logical blocks: (480 GB/447 GiB)
[  403.649407] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  403.650131] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  403.650136] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 67 00 10 08
[  403.651570] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[  403.652213] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 524287 logical blocks > dev_max (65535 logical blocks)
[  403.672647]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 sdb5 sdb6 sdb7 sdb8
[  403.679223] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  434.180233] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  434.180241] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f ba db 00 00 01 00 00
[  434.180422] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
[  434.180429] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f ba dc 00 00 01 00 00
[  434.186259] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  434.350439] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  434.365648] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  444.409122] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  444.409129] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  444.409133] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  444.525455] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  444.540536] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  444.540544] sd 2:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  444.540547] sd 2:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  444.540564] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT cmd_age=40s
[  444.540569] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f ba dc 00 00 01 00 00
[  444.540571] print_req_error: 1 callbacks suppressed
[  444.540576] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339712 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[  444.540600] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT cmd_age=40s
[  444.540603] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f ba db 00 00 01 00 00
[  444.540607] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339456 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[  444.540670] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  444.540677] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339456 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  444.540682] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 6288128, async page read
[  444.540701] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  444.540705] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339457 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  444.540707] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 6288129, async page read
[  444.540719] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  444.540722] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339458 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  444.540724] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 6288130, async page read
[  444.540735] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  444.540737] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339459 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  444.540739] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 6288131, async page read
[  444.540749] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  444.540752] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339460 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  444.540754] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 6288132, async page read
[  444.540764] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  444.540767] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 532339461 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  444.540769] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 6288133, async page read
[  444.540779] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
```

Any suggestions on how can I access my disk at least to format it?  Why discovered bad blocks stops it from being accessible?

Comment: Is the SSD directly connected via SATA or via USB-to-SATA connector? If it is the latter connect it directly to avoid problems.

Comment: It is connected via USB to SATA.

Comment: Then the USB to SATA connector is most likely the problem. I would assume that those cheap adapters have never been tested with devices that have bad blocks, hence it fails and the drive becomes inaccessible. Connect the drive directly to an SATA controller, best in the chipset of the PC. In any way I would recommend to perform a secure erase on the SSD and then recycle it. An SSD with bad blocks can't e trusted anymore. Saving data on it is just like a lottery with a chance that you never get you data back.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a [GParted](https://gparted.org/) live USB to see if you can format it from there.

You can try a different SATA / M2 slot, a different cable and if possible a different machine, but I know from my own SSDs that when they go, they go quickly and stop being detected at all.

Comment: I see, so I suppose surface scan speed up that issue.

Comment: @sphinks Yes it's a possibility as it will go through the entire disk, if it was already about to die this wont have helped. People have suggested that sometimes you can bring a dead SSD (SATA drives at least) back by attaching the power connector but not the data and power cycling it a few times. It didn't work for me but it might be worth a shot.